# How to return CompletionStage<Response> both synchronously and asynchronously in Quarkus?

Tags: java, asynchronous, quarkus, mutiny

I have endpoint, which can return both sync and async results

```
@POST
@Path("/create-account")
public CompletionStage<Response> createAccount(...) {

   if (preconditions) {
       return myAsyncFunction(...);
   }
   else {
       // how to return error immediately???
       return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build(); // incorrect return type
   }

}
```

How to return something deliberately, i.e. sync?

Answer (score 3):

A [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) is an interface that models a stage of a possibly asynchronous computation, that performs an action or computes a value when another CompletionStage completes.

So it can be the result of a synchronous or an asynchronous operation.

The `CompletableFuture` is a JRE class tha implements the `CompletionStage` interface.
You can create and return a completed `CompletableFuture`, which implements the [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) using the [CompletableFuture.completedFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completedFuture-U-) static method.

```
 return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build())
```

The result returned will be already completed with the response provided.

Comment: Should not parametrization of class CompletableFuture move to the method completedFuture?
`return CompletableFuture.<Response>completedFuture(Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build())`

Comment: Good observation. The parameterization should not be in the class. It could also be omited for brevity, since the type used is explicit. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged this as mutiny.
I assume the async function is a uni or a multy.
If you use restaesy-mutiny, you just can return the mutly/uni itself, as described in the guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-reactive

```
 @GET
@Path("{id}")
public Uni<Response> getSingle(Long id) {
    return Fruit.findById(client, id)
            .onItem().transform(fruit -> fruit != null ? Response.ok(fruit) : Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND))
            .onItem().transform(ResponseBuilder::build);
}
```

To handle precondition, you can create an uni with the response itself. Something like:

```
Uni.createFrom()
            .item(Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build())
```

Best is to check out Mutiny guides itself:
https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides
To understand how to handle errors etc.